# How do I make a splash screen that supports all android versions in kotlin compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-splashscreen

I wanted to make a splash screen for my app and I found an article on the internet and added them to my app.

**I follow this documentation.**
https://developersancho.medium.com/jetpack-compose-splash-screen-api-36ca40c6196b

In this documentation, if you examine it, there are two pictures at the bottom, one represents android 11 and the other represents android 12, so the codes made by this guy say that they work both on android 12 and above, but when I apply this code to my app, it works properly on android 12 and above but android 12 and under the screen goes black and the splash icon looks bigger than normal. I did a lot of research but I couldn't solve this problem, can you help me please? What path should I follow?

**hear is my code:**

**SplashActivity.kt**

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
@SuppressLint("CustomSplashScreen")
class SplashActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    private val viewModel: SplashScreenViewModel by viewModels()
    private val tokenManager = TokenManager(this)
    val activity = this
    private val errMsg = "ERROR!"

    private fun navigateToMain(isTokenExist: Boolean) {
        val intent = Intent(this@SplashActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("isTokenExist", isTokenExist)
        startActivity(intent)
        finish()
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            val splashScreen = installSplashScreen()
            splashScreen.setKeepOnScreenCondition { true }
        }
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        if (viewModel.state.value.error) {
            Toast.makeText(this@SplashActivity, errMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        }

        var doOnce = true

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            viewModel.state.collect {
                if (it.completed && doOnce) {
                    activity.navigateToMain(!it.error)
                    doOnce = false
                }
            }
        }

        lifecycleScope.launchWhenCreated {
            tokenManager.getRefreshToken().collect { refreshToken ->
                if (refreshToken != null) {
                    if (viewModel.state.value.error) {
                        delay(2000)
                        activity.navigateToMain(false)
                    }
                    activity.viewModel.refreshAccessToken(refreshToken)
                } else {
                    delay(2000)
                    activity.navigateToMain(false)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Themes.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Diyetkolik" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar" />

    <style name="DialogTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/DatePickerLightColor</item>
    </style>



    <style name="Theme.SplashScreenApp" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">#3FC6E3</item>

    </style>

    <style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreenApp">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/ic_background_splash</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

**Themes.xml(v31)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="SplashScreenTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#3FC6E3</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@drawable/ic_background_splash_12</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimationDuration">800</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/Theme.SplashScreenApp</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

**Manifest.kt**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

  tools:node="remove"/>


    <application
       ...>

       <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/SplashScreenTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>



       <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.Diyetkolik">
        
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
                android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.app.lib_name"
                android:value="" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**Build.gradle(module)**

I add splash api dependency under the dependencies.

```
 implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1")
```

**compile sdk and target sdk versions**

```
android {
    
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 33
```

Comment: the api works with Android 12 and higher only, that's also mentioned in the article you linked.

Comment: but he shows android 12 and higher and android 12 and below ? isn't he ?

Comment: If this documentation only describes 12 and above, as you said, then there are people who support or do this under normal conditions, so I'm talking about a properly working splash screen on Android 12 and above and below. How can I do this?

Comment: for that you would have to create a new activity/fragment only for the splash screen and instantiate a CountDownTimer in the activity/fragment or a at the end of the timer navigate/startActivity to your main screen . Check this : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-create-a-splash-screen-in-android-using-kotlin/

Comment: Thank you for answer but your recommendation is not a best practice because it contains postDelayed() and this is not a good solution. I 've solved my problem from this web site https://vtsen.hashnode.dev/implement-default-splash-screen-prior-to-android-12. I edited this documentation for myself and it worked.

Comment: There is an official library for making splash screens that work almost the same for old and new versions of Android: https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/core/splashscreen/SplashScreen

Answer (score 0):

This AndroidX library works consistently across all Android APIs (>5.0)

Add the dependency:

```kotlin
implementation("androidx.core:core-splashscreen:1.0.1")
```

Add the following `style` to your `themes.xml` or `styles.xml`

```xml
    <style name="SplashTheme" parent="Theme.SplashScreen.IconBackground">
        <item name="windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon">@mipmap/ic_launcher</item>
        <item name="windowSplashScreenBackground">#444444</item>
        <item name="postSplashScreenTheme">@style/SyncplayMainScreenTheme</item>
    </style>
```

Replace `windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon` with the logo you want.

Replace `windowSplashScreenBackground` with the background color you want.

Replace `postSplashScreenTheme` with the actual first entry activity theme.

In your `AndroidManifest.xml`, change the theme of your entry activity (MainActivity or whatever) to the splash theme, then the library will take care of changing the theme after the splashscreen is done.

For example (notice how the theme is SplashTheme and not the actual activity theme)

```xml
<activity
            android:name="app.activities.HomeActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:theme="@style/SplashTheme">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Last but not least, in your Kotlin code, add this line to your onCreate overridden method BEFORE the super call (super.onCreate):

```kotlin
override fun onCreate(b: Bundle?) {
    installSplashScreen()
    super.onCreate(b)
}
```

That's it :)

Comment: I have used this solution but shows a blank screen on API 11 and then shows the Activity

Comment: @MuhammadYousuf You probably didnt set the XML things properly. Make sure you create the SplashScreen theme in themes.xml properly with a valid logo drawable. The most important thing is to set your activity's theme in AndroidManifest.xml to the splash screen theme you created in themes.xml

Comment: Actually, I was trying to implement a splash screen for versions below Android 12 and could not achieve it. It worked for versions Android 12 and above.

Comment: @MuhammadYousuf You don't need a dedicated`themes.xml(v31)` for Android 31 and above. Just use one `themes.xml`, inherit a theme from `Theme.SplashScreen`, then you can set your logo with the attribute `windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon`. Your splash screen is black because the attribute is not present in your `themes.xml` (i think it's only present in your themes.xml(v31)`

Comment: I am only using themes.xml not themes.xml(v31) or any for specific Android versions. I wanted to show the Splash icon on Android 11 and below but windowSplashScreenAnimatedIcon does not show any icon on Android 11 just a blank screen.

Comment: Can the icon be not a circle ?